# Question about the inversion method for simulation of random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, inference, quantiles, random-generation

In the method called inversion we have :

Let $U$ ~ unif(0,1)  denote a uniform random variable on $(0,1)$.

Then : $\mathbb{P}(F^{-1}(U))$ = $\mathbb{P}(U \leq F(x))=F(x)$

so $F^{-1}(U)$ has distribution function $F$. Hence we can simulate a realisation of $X$ by simulating a realisation of $F^{-1}(U)$.

For example, if we want to simulate exponential distribution, the first step is to find $F^{-1}$  and then we have to take values $u∼U(0,1)$ and finally pass through $F^{-1}(U)$  to obtain $x$.

My question is : why do we need to use this approach ? because if we want to simulate exponential distrbution, why we dont it directly for example :

```
rexp(5, 4)
```

I don't understand the usefulness of the uniform distribution.

Some help woud be appreciated

Comment: The question is not really meaningful since the inversion method is a (correct) universal probability result, while the call to `rexp` is a programming issue in a specific language.

Comment: @Xi'an  I'm not saying that the inversion method is not correct. I'm just saying that I dont understand the approach of this method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inversion method is a universal method to generate random variables from a distribution with distribution function $F$ (given uniformly distributed random numbers). For some distributions, there are more efficient methods to do this, and therefore the inversion method is not used. But this has to do with specific characteristics of the distribution we are interested in. If you read the R help pages, you will find that the command `rexp` indeed does not use the inversion method, because there is a better alternative in the literature. But for example `rweibull`, for Weibull distributed random numbers, uses the inversion method, probably because there is nothing better on offer in the literature (I don't know all literature of course).

Comment: Re. Weibull: this difference is strange since a Weibull variate is simply an exponential variate to a power $k$.

Comment: @Xi'an Fair enough. I don't know why that is, just that it is said on the help page.